# Find the gcd of the following Gaussian integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, gaussian-integers

$\gcd(5 + 8i, 3 + 2i)$ in $Z[i]$.

I found it and I got 1 then I look at the manual solution and it turns out it can be i or -i or -1 or 1. why?

Comment: gcds are unique only up to unit factors (associates), e.g. for integers the units are $\pm1$ so the gcd is unique up to sign. But we normalize the unit factor by defining the gcd to be nonnegative. In more general domains there may be no simply way to do such unit normalization. In this case any associate is also **a** gcd (but not **the** gcd).

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with the definition of **a** gcd. I am not sure what definition you are using. Possibly you were told that a gcd of two Gaussian integers $u$ and $v$ is  any Gaussian integer $z$ that divides both $u$ and $v$, and such that any common divisor of $u$ and $v$ divides $z$.

If we use that definition, one can show that if $z$ is a gcd of $u$ and $v$, and $\epsilon$ is any unit, then $\epsilon z$ is also a gcd of $u$ and $v$. Conversely, if $z\ne 0$ and $z'$ are gcd's of $u$ and $v$, then $z'=\epsilon z$ for some unit $\epsilon$.

So gcd is not unique, it is determined only up to multiplication by a unit. There is no such thing as **the** gcd.

In the Gaussian integers, the units are $1,-1,i,-i$.

Comment: so all the associates are also "gcds"?

Comment: Yes. I did not know whether you knew the term "associate," so I avoided it. But the stuff about $\epsilon$ says that $z$ is a gcd of $u$ and $v$ if and only if all associates of $z$ are gcd of $u$ and $v$. In the integers, it would be like saying that $-1$ is a gcd of $3$ and $5$. In the integers, one chooses to use the positive associate. In more general situations, there is no "nice" way to pick out a favourite among the associates.

Comment: Well, sometimes there are nice ways. For example, think of the polynomials with rational (or real) coefficients. One can define gcd of two polynomials $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ very much in the style I used for the Gaussian integers. There are then technically infinitely many gcd of $P$ and $Q$. But it is traditional to use the monic one (lead coefficient equal to $1$).

Comment: By the way, how did you find that $1$ is a gcd? One can use a variant of the Euclidean Algorithm. But an easier way is to note that if $z$ divides both, then the norm of $z$ divides the two norms in the usual sense. However, the two norms are $89$ and $13$, which are coprime.

Comment: I used the variant of the Euclidean algorithm. Ohhh nice. I have to do a similar problem in which I have to find the prime factors of a Gaussian integer and I think that's the way to go